# Write on a NFC tag using simple php form

Tags: php, nfc

I'm using NFC for the first time, I have to write a simple php form with some data (id, name, qty, etc) and store these values on an NFC tag (I would use GET or POST methods).

 
How can I store these data on an NFC tag? I have a GoToTags device to store information in a NFC tags, but I don't think I can use it to store my "custom" values.

Comment: How should your NFC tag and the PHP web application interact? Should the NFC reader + NFC tag be connected to the server or should they be connected to the client?

Comment: The NFC reader + NFC tag will be connected to the client, I just have to write a simple form in php, click on save, and store the value in the NFC tag throught the GoToTags device

Comment: this will not be possible without some sort of client application that interacts directly with the device.

Comment: I have to correct myself. Looks like it might be possible (in a couple if years when the newly proposed nfc api is available in all major browsers): http://www.w3.org/2012/nfc/web-api/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider some sort of client application, such as?

Comment: Such as a program that is able to interface with a hardware NFC reader/writer. AFAIK no webbrowser is able to do so at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

A PHP web application's code is executed on the server side, so if you want to interact with hardware (NFC reader, NFC tag) on the client side, you will need to use something else besides PHP code to access that client side hardware.

The client-side NFC reader would typically not act as a web server and therefore won't be accessible through HTTP GET/POST requests (see the exception below), so you will have to find something else.

Your web application will also consist of a web page (HTML, CSS, (Java) script) that is displayed and executed on the client side. This web page could, for instance, contain script code that is executed within the client web browser.

- As GeraldSchneider commented, there is the NFC Web API, but this is not yet available in most (any?) web browsers.
- An alternative could be a Java applet embedded into the web page. If the NFC reader is PC/SC compliant, you could, for instance, use the Java smartcardio API within that applet to access the reader.
- Yet another possibility would be to create a browser plug-in that supports communication between your web page and the NFC device.
- If you really want/need to use HTTP GET/POST requests, you could provide a client-side application that acts as a web server and processes your GET/POST requests. That client-side application would then access the NFC reader/NFC tag based on these requests. However, besides the PHP web application/the web page you would also need to provide that separate client application and the application needs to run on the client while your web page is accessed.